# Calculation/manipulation of numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sum, numpy-einsum

Looking to make the this calculation as quickly as possible. I have X as n x m numpy array. I want to define Y to be the following:

`Y_11 = 1 / (exp(X_11-X_11) + exp(X_11-X_12) + ... exp(X_11 - X_1N) ).`

or for Y_00

`1/np.sum(np.exp(X[0,0]-X[0,:]))`

So basically, Y is also n x m where the i,j element is the 1 / sum_j' exp(X_ij - X_ij')

Any tips would be great! Thanks.

*Sample code as requested:*

```
np.random.seed(111)
J,K = 110,120
X = np.random.rand(J,K)
Y = np.zeros((J,K))
for j in range(J):
    for k in range(K):
        Y[j,k] = 1/np.sum(np.exp(X[j,k]-X[j,:]))

# note each row will sum to 1 under this operation
np.sum(Y,axis=1)
```

Comment: Where did the `exp` calls go in your second expression?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that I dropped the exp(). I also added some code.

Comment: This is now a good question. In the future, it would be great if you could write stuff upfront like it is now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are few fully vectorized approaches -

```
def vectorized_app1(X):
    return 1/np.exp(X[:,None] - X[...,None]).sum(1)

def vectorized_app2(X):
    exp_vals = np.exp(X)
    return 1/(exp_vals[:,None]/exp_vals[...,None]).sum(1)

def vectorized_app3(X):
    exp_vals = np.exp(X)
    return 1/np.einsum('ij,ik->ij',exp_vals,1/exp_vals)
```

**Tricks used and lessons learnt**

- Extend dimensions with `None/np.newaxis` to bring in broadcasting and perform everything in a vectorized manner.
- `np.exp` is an expensive operation. So, using it on broadcasted huge array would be costly. So, the trick used is : `exp(A-B) = exp(A)/exp(B)`. Thus, we perform `np.exp(X)` upfront and then perform broadcasted divisions.
- Those sum-reductions could be implemented with `np.einsum`. This brings in memory-efficiency as we won't have to create huge broadcasted arrays and this effects in massive performance boost.

Runtime test -

```
In [111]: # Setup input, X
     ...: np.random.seed(111)
     ...: J,K = 110,120
     ...: X = np.random.rand(J,K)
     ...: 

In [112]: %timeit original_approach(X)
1 loop, best of 3: 322 ms per loop

In [113]: %timeit vectorized_app1(X)
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop

In [114]: %timeit vectorized_app2(X)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop

In [115]: %timeit vectorized_app3(X)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.01 ms per loop
```

Looks like `einsum` showed its magic again with **`100x+`** speedup!

Comment: Very useful answer. Thanks for all the explanations.

Comment: Thank you! One issue however is sometimes A or B has large values so I get an error. My thought about going with exp(A-B) is that I shrink a lot of them and can put in an np.min(A-B, 200) or similar to avoid errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Kevin What exactly is the error? What does it say?

Comment: overflow in exp. I just discovered bigfloat but will need to spend time seeing how to implement with my code -- and see if it works with knitro.

Comment: @Kevin Hmm or I guess you can stick to `vectorized_app1` for those cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a first step at reducing the double loop:

```
def foo2(X):
    Y = np.zeros_like(X)
    for k in range(X.shape[1]):
        Y[:,k]=1/np.exp(X[:,[k]]-X[:,:]).sum(axis=1)
    return Y
```

I suspect I can also remove the `k` loop, but I have to spend more time figuring out just what it is doing.  That `X[:,[k]]-X[:,:]` isn't obvious (in the big picture).

Another step:

```
Z = np.stack([X[:,[k]]-X for k in range(X.shape[1])],2)
Y = 1/np.exp(Z).sum(axis=1)
```

which can be further refined (with too much trial and error) with

```
Z = X[:,None,:]-X[:,:,None]
```

Comment: Great answer. Very minor comment: in your last parentheses, did you possibly mean "*without* too much trial and error".

Comment: No, I tried a number of alternatives.  There are various ways in which `X` can be expanded to 3d.  And 3 axis that it can be summed on.  I wasn't as systematic as I could have been.